# Print out a text in the middle of a rectangle

Tags: c++

I want to print out a rectangle and in the middle I want to output a preferred text.

So In the terminal it should look like:

```
Enter width and height: 5 6

+-----+
|     |
|     |
|     |
|     |
|     |
+-----+
```

Then in the middle of the rectangle `(height/2)` it should print out "`Hey`". It doesn't fit in this example because the format on reddit is a bit different than my compiler.

However I wonder how I could make this happen? I can create the rectangle but I cannot seem to create a "`when`" statement, as in "`when mid occurs, print out "Hey"`.

I need help finding a way to write such statement.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void print_row (int const width)
{
    cout << '+' << '-';
    for (int i = 1; i < width; ++i)
    {
        cout << '-';
    }
    cout << '+' << endl;
}

void print_rectangle (int const width, int const height)
{
    int mid = height/2;
    print_row(width);
    for (int i {}; i < height; ++i)
    {
        cout << '|' << setw(width+1) << '|' << endl;
        if (mid)
        {
             cout << "Hey" << endl;
        }
    }
    print_row(width);
}

int main()
{
    int width {};
    int height {};
    cout << "Enter width and height: ";
    cin >> width >> height;
    print_rectangle(width,height);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please remove the double spacing and use proper indentation.

Comment: `if (i == mid)` is closer to what you want, but you'll need to break printing the left side and right side into two statements or add the left and right printing to the conditional *and* skip the normal printing when it is true.

Answer (score 0):

first of all validate your width and height in your `print_rectangle`

```
String output = "hey";
if(width < output.length() || height <= 0) return;
```

and change the for loop like this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        if (i == mid) {
             int spacing = width - output.length();
             cout <<'|'<< setw(width-spacing/2) << output << setw(spacing/2+1) << '|' << endl;
             continue;
        }
        cout << '|' << setw(width+1) << '|' << endl;
    }
```