# C++ | Input the following string inside a rectangle

Tags: c++

I would like to input the following code inside a rectangle, so that the output would be the rectangle with my printed text.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main() {

    cout <<" * Programming Assignment *" << endl;
    cout <<" * Data Structures *" << endl;
    cout <<" * Author: Hello World  * " << endl;
    cout <<" * Due Date: September, 7th * " << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the text OUTPUT I want to be in the Rectangle:

```
* Programming Assignment *
* Data Structures *
* Author: Hello World *
* Due Date: September, 7th *
```

Do you have any tips on how to do this, I've already checked the tutorial bellow, but that did not help clarify my answer:

[Print out a text in the middle of a rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70527447/print-out-a-text-in-the-middle-of-a-rectangle)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `#include <iomanip>` header, which includes convenient objects which you can pass into `cout`, to manipulate the output: `std::setw(width)` to specify that the next thing you print (text in our case) will have to be padded to have exactly `width` characters, `std::setfill(' ')` to specify with which character you pad the text, and `std::left` to tell to align the text to the left, and pad with spaces to the right.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
using namespace std;

void print_box_border(int width, bool is_top) {
    if (is_top) { cout << "┌"; }
    else { cout << "└"; }
    for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
        cout << "─";
    }
    if (is_top) { cout << "┐\n"; }
    else { cout << "┘\n"; }
    
}

void print_box_row(int width, const char * text) {
    cout << "│" << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(width) << std::left << text <<  "│\n";
}

int main()
{
    int box_width = 50;
    print_box_border(box_width, /*is_top*/ true);
    print_box_row(box_width, " * Programming Assignment *");
    print_box_row(box_width, " * Data Structures *");
    print_box_row(box_width, " * Author: Hello World  * ");
    print_box_row(box_width, " * Due Date: September, 7th * ");
    print_box_border(box_width, /*is_top*/ false);
    return 0;
}
```

Output I get:

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ * Programming Assignment *                       │
│ * Data Structures *                              │
│ * Author: Hello World  *                         │
│ * Due Date: September, 7th *                     │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```